# AC mains isolated voltage measurement

Tags: voltage-measurement, isolated

I am looking for a AC mains voltage measurement circuit for my controller which has to be isolated. There are a lot of circuit using step down transformer, but all of them are too large for my project. Is there a possibility to use miniature SMT transformers, such as audio? Could they be used for isolation? After isolation I could rectify this voltage and use voltage divider.

**UPDATE:** The size of the transformer must not exceed 10x10x10mm. Transformer could be used for only isolation. The voltage I want to measure is 220VAC/50Hz.

Could this circuit do the job for the measurement? What about its safety and accuracy? https://microcontrollerslab.com/ac-voltage-measurement-using-microcontroller/

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: You will find the isolation rating of the transformers on the datasheet but since that's not what they're intended for it sounds like a bad idea. You could [edit] your question to give your dimension limits and you might get some answers. See also a discussion on https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/measuring-voltage-with-isolation-transformer/.

Comment: "As small as possible" isn't a good specification. You probably don't want to pay for "as small as possible". Instead use numbered dimensions and isolation voltage - probably 1 to 4 kV rating. You're also going to need to consider creepage clearance between the pins.

Comment: What is the measurement used for? What level of accuracy do you need? Is it OK if the system requires an initial calibration for accuracy? Or does it need to be accurate as assembled?

Comment: Voltage measurement would be used for power usage calculations by controller software. Better if no calibration needed.

Comment: What level of accuracy do you need? Is 1% good enough?

Comment: I think 1% is good enough.

Comment: Tom, if you are done here you should pick an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an analog isolation amplifier or digitize the signal and pass  it over an isolator. If you have to provide a DC-DC converter the frequency will be much higher than mains frequency so that transformer can be compact, and the signal isolation can be accomplished by opto-isolation or other methods (magnetic, RF, capacitive coupling etc.) that are built into commercial isolators.

Mains-frequency transformers tend to be large because the frequency is so low, and even more so if you want them to behave accurately as a potential transformer.

Comment: AC isolation for measurement is such a pain in the ass haha.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be aiming to go down this route (similar example): -

[image]

The galvanic isolation is from the [ADuM5401](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adum5401_5402_5403_5404.pdf). It provides digital channel isolation and isolated power to the 1 Mbps [AD7091](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7091R.pdf). It has a resolution of 12 bits so is pretty adequate for most applications but, if you dig a little deeper, you'll find that you interface with a whole host of other ADCs.

Plus, there are tons of other similar digital isolators to choose from not just from ADI but TI too.

> *The size of the transformer must not exceed 10x10x10mm.*

It could be made to fit; isolator on one mini circuit board with the ADC stacked on top on another small PCB.

[Similar answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/208379/arduino-how-to-read-sensor-without-common-ground).

Answer (score 1):

You may have other requirements that are not mentioned in the question. However, the following is possibly a solution for what you are looking for -- a capacitative voltage divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcf79z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitors C1 and C2 have high impedance to 50Hz or 60Hz voltages, as well as allowing the measurement circuit to "float" in relationship to the mains supply. Capacitors need to be rated to carry the full mains supply voltage. Per @transistor below, they should be X or Y rated (he isn't sure which). The output of the capacitative voltage divider is measured across C3 and is equal to

\$V_{measure} = V_{in}\frac{\displaystyle \frac{1}{C3}}{\displaystyle \frac{1}{C1} + \frac{1}{C2} + \frac{1}{C3}} = V_{in}\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \frac{C3}{C1}+\frac{C3}{C2}+1}\$

*provided* the impedance of the measuring circuit is significantly higher than the impedance of C3. V_measure_A and V_measure_B should be fed as inputs into a high input impedance differential amplifier.

The capacitors will induce a phase shift, so if you are looking for zero crossings, and/or need to measure phase angle for power calculations, this circuit will not work.

Edit: Please take note of advice in comments, especially @Transistor

Comment: The capacitors would need to be X or Y-rated (I can't remember which is which) for mains safety. Calibration is likely to be a headache with the tolerance of the capacitors. OP also needs to be aware that this will introduce a phase-shift which will most likely make it useless if it's for an energy meter.

Comment: @Transistor X2 to be placed across the line.